# Character replacement encoding php

Tags: php, html, regex, wordpress, utf-8

I have a string that I want to replace all 'a' characters to the greek 'α' character. I don't want to convert the html elements inside the string ie `<a href="http://a-url-with-a-characters">text</a>`.

The function:

```
function grstrletter($string){

    $skip = false;
    $str_length = strlen($string);

    for ($i=0; $i < $str_length; $i++){

        if($string[$i] == '<'){
            $skip = true;
        }

        if($string[$i] == '>'){
            $skip = false;
        }

        if ($string[$i]=='a' && !$skip){
            $string[$i] = 'α';
        }
    }

    return $string;

}
```

Another function I have made works perfectly but it doesn't take in account the hmtl elements.

```
function grstrletter_no_html($string){

 return strtr($string, array('a' => 'α'));

}
```

I also tried a lot of encoding functions that php offers with no luck.

When I echo the greek letter the browser output it without a problem. When I return the string the browser outputs the classic strange question mark inside a triangle whenever the replace was occured.

My header has `<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">` and I also tried it with php `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');` but again with no luck.

The string comes from a database in UTF-8 and the site is in wordpress so I just use the wordpress functions to get the content I want. I don't think is a db problem because when I use my function `grstrletter_no_html()` everything works fine.

The problem seems to happen when I iterate the string character by character.

The file is saved as UTF-8 without BOM (notepad++). I tried also to change the encoding of the file with no luck again.

I also tried to replace the greek letter with the corresponding html entity `&#945;`     and `&alpha;` but again same results.

I haven't tried yet any regex.

I would appreciate any help and thanks in advance.

Tried: [Greek characters encoding works in HTML but not in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15398251/greek-characters-encoding-works-in-html-but-not-in-php?rq=1)

**EDIT**

The solution based on **deceze** brilliant answer:

```
function grstrletter($string){

    $skip = false;
    $str_length = strlen($string);

    for ($i=0; $i < $str_length; $i++){

        if($string[$i] == '<'){
            $skip = true;
        }

        if($string[$i] == '>'){
            $skip = false;
        }

        if ($string[$i]=='a' && !$skip){
            $part1 = substr($string, 0, $i);
            $part1 = $part1 . 'α';
            $string = $part1 . substr($string, $i+1);
        }
    }

    return $string;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're setting only a single byte of your string. Example:

```
$str = "\x00\x00\x00";

var_dump(bin2hex($str));

$str[1] = "\xff\xff";

var_dump(bin2hex($str));
```

Output:

```
string(6) "000000"
string(6) "00ff00"
```

You're setting a two-byte character, but only one byte of it is actually pushed into the string. The second result here would have to be `00ffff` for your code to work.

What you need is to cut the string from `0` to `$i - 1`, concatenate the `'α'` into it, then concatenate the rest of the string `$i + 1` to end onto it if you want to insert a multibyte character. That, or work with *characters* instead of *bytes* using the [mbstring](http://php.net/mbstring) functions.

For more background information, see [What Every Programmer Absolutely, Positively Needs To Know About Encodings And Character Sets To Work With Text](http://kunststube.net/encoding/).