# greek characters not appearing correctly to/from database - html, php, mysqli

Tags: php, html, mysqli, utf-8, phpmyadmin

My database has collation `utf8-general-ci` [I also tried `greek-general-ci` with worse results].

When I insert a row with Greek values directly through phpMyAdmin, it appears on my html page like this: '??????'.

When I insert a row through my html form, it appears correctly on the html-outcome page, but on phpMyAdmin it looks like this: 'ÎœÎ±ÏÎ¯Î±'.

I can deal with that, since I'm only doing this for a university project, so I can just insert all rows through my html form, but I'm really curious why this is happening.

On my html files I have 
`<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">`
and when I had `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');` on my php files it messed seriously with my pages so I must not include it. Also tried including `$mysqli->set_charset("utf8");` but only errors appeared.

I have also checked [Greek characters encoding works in HTML but not in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15398251/greek-characters-encoding-works-in-html-but-not-in-php) but we don't have the same problem. Should I change the httpd.conf file however?

Answer (score 0):

First of all check your table's collation. It's not linked to database collation. 
Your table collation should be utf8-general-ci too.

```
<? header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8'); 
$mysqli->set_charset("utf8"); ?>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
```

When all these four settings are active; 
You should able to insert, update or read **UTF-8 INSERTED** data successfully

My guess is your problem occured because your old data is not utf-8 encoded. 
You should create a batch script;

1. which selects all data from table
2. convert it to utf-8 using `mb_convert_encoding`
3. and updated old data

to fix your data.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Your first suggestion didn't work, I will try the batch script soon.